# How do I call a Public Shared Function from another form object?

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I have a *WebMethod* tagged function developed for one web form that I would like to re-use in another.  The easiest way would be to just re-use it in place, but the obvious syntax guesses aren't working.

My history is C++ & C#, so when trying to reference a shared (static) method my first go-to is `classname.method(parameters)`.  But that didn't work, so I went to Google and it said the syntax is `classname.method(parameters)`.

I tried adding the word `Public` to first page's object definition (it remains in the code cuts below), but the hint of protection problems didn't yield results.  I also tried using `Imports Directories_DeptPhoneList` in the *PeopleSearch* code, to no avail.

I'm hoping to find a solution better than "rip the function out of the *WebForm* and put it in a shared class with another layer of call overhead".

Backing code from the first page:

```
Public Partial Class Directories_DeptPhoneList
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    ...
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function SearchRequested(key As String) As String
        ... SQL lookup, results formatted into table rows, one row per match
        ... str = "<tr>....</tr>" no <table> tag, just guts of the table
        Return str
    End Function
    ...
End Class
```

The second "search that and more too" page backing code:

```
Partial Class Directories_PeopleSearch
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    ...
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function DoSearch(key As String) As String
        Dim deptRows As String = Directories_DeptPhoneList.SearchRequested(key)
        ... More lookups & data formatting another str = "<tr>....</tr>" 
        Return deptRows & str
    End Function
    ...
End Class
```

I'd expect to be able to call the Shared function, but Visual Studio redlines `Directories_DeptPhoneList.SearchRequested` on the method call from the *PeopleSearch* object.  The error complaint reads:

> Directories_DeptPhoneList is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: The method is not the issue.  If you actually read the error message you can see that it's talking about the class being inaccessible, not the method.  That seems to suggest that those two classes are members of different namespaces or declared in different assemblies.

Comment: I did actually read it, thank you.

The two classes reside side-by-side in the same web project. I have no explicit namespace definitions in the project at all.

Both files were created in the same way -- using Visual Studio, Add New / Web Forms (with master) -- in the same folder of the same solution -- I don't know how they'd be in different namespaces.  But if you have some idea in that area, I'm listening.  :-)  and reading.

Comment: This question is still unanswered -- I have continued researching and have found nothing relevant.  I was hoping the smugness of the only attempt to answer meant that person may have some tidbit of knowledge to impart -- but no such luck.  No one has come up with even a suggestion.

There still appears no way to call a shared method from another Web Form from within the current Web Form, despite both forms being in the same folder of the same project.  Any ideas??????  

The error message implies the objects themselves are hidden from each other, but I have no namespace declarations.

Comment: 19 days ... 37 views ... not one suggestion??   

Who would've thought calling a public function from a public class in the same project would be so difficult?  I've been banging my head against the wall on this one, and have found another piece of code that would be great to re-use on another page, but cannot access it there either.